# Basic auth on Drupal 8 sometimes fails (uses Anonymous instead)

Tags: basic-authentication, drupal-8

I have a drupal 8 (8.7.6) installation. It runs on both a Ubuntu VM on Windows and also on iPage. I've written a simple custom module that implements a Content Entity.

I connect using JSON:API and basic_auth and it works for a while, then eventually stops working. Client doesn't seem to matter (both cURL and a custom app).

If I uninstall and re-install the custom module, then it seems to fail more often. After that, if I remove/re-add an admin account then I can connect with that account for a while.

Looking at the drupal logs, I see the failing calls come in as: "Anonymous (not verified)" rather than the supplied credentials.

Any ideas on how to debug this or pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same issue and it turned out to be because of the core flood protection. This can be fixed by truncating the `flood` table or by changing the `user_limit` value in the `user.flood` config to a higher number.